# What does a C++ compiler do if you make a template function but no deterministic instances of its use

Tags: c++

I understand that writing template functions is just writing things in a general way and that the compiler is supposed to write actual instances of functions based on the rest of the program. But consider the following program:

```
#inlcude <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

template <typename T> void ptr_swap(T * a, T * b)
{
    T * temp = a; 
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

int main()
{
     srand(time(NULL));
     std::string s1("Obama"), s2("Hillary");
     int i1(1), i2(69);
     if (rand() & 1 == 1) ptr_swap(&s1, &s2); 
     else ptr_swap(&i1, &i2);
     return 0;
}
```

How does the compiler know whether to construct a ptr_swap function for `string`s or `int`s? Does it just make sure to be "ready for anything" and thus write 2 functions

```
void ptr_swap(std::string * a, std::string * b)
{
    std::string * temp = a; 
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

void ptr_swap (int * a, int * b)
{
    int * temp = a; 
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

????

Comment: Templates are instantiated at compile-time. The value of `rand()` is determined at runtime.

Comment: Your `ptr_swap` does not swap at all, since the pointers are passed by value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler knows it must construct **both**. So it does.

Comment: What if I made the program even more ridiculous by having a ptr_swap function that would randomly use 1 of 1000 possibilities of argument types? Would the compiler create all 1000?

Comment: @FailedSoftwareDeveloper: Yes.  What other sensible option does it have?

Answer (score 2):

The function will be synthesized when it is *instantiated* (i.e. when the function is called with known template parameters).

So the compiler sees that you call the function with `std::string` -- then the template function `ptr_swap<std::string>` must be created.

Since your program did not call it with `bool`s, it won't bother creating `ptr_swap<bool>`.